# SQL Subquery Invalid Column Name

Tags: sql, subquery

```
SELECT 
    ISBN, CopyNo, DateOut 
FROM 
    LOAN 
WHERE 
    **Title** = (SELECT Title FROM Book WHERE Title LIKE '%Stuart Little%');


SELECT 
    ISBN, Title, YearPublish 
FROM 
    Book 
WHERE 
    **Name** = (SELECT Name FROM Author WHERE Name LIKE '%Pan Books%');
```

I can't seem to find any problems with my code above. It keeps saying "Invalid column name" when I put my cursor over the bold items. The columns do exist and I've tried to refresh and open and close the program :( I can't seem to resolve this. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

The "subquery" might return more than one records, so you can't use "=". Use "in" instead:

```
SELECT ISBN, CopyNo, DateOut FROM LOAN WHERE Title in (SELECT Title FROM Book WHERE Title LIKE '%Stuart Little%');

SELECT ISBN, Title, YearPublish FROM Book WHERE Name in (SELECT Name FROM Author WHERE Name LIKE '%Pan Books%');
```

Answer (score 0):

The columns exist, but that's not how `=` works. You need to use the keyword `IN` instead of `=`. Here's a little more information about it: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php...

You could also do something like this (if I correctly understood the schema)...
`SELECT ISBN, Title, YearPublish FROM Book, Author WHERE Name LIKE '%Pan Books%';`

Answer (score 0):

It's like you've mixed columns from different tables. You should post your table structure to get a right answer. So Let me guess - a `LOAN` table haven't got the `TITLE` column. It seems it belongs to the `BOOK` table. I see that `ISBN` field exists in both tables so you should use the following. Note that you should avoid using `=` with subquery because it can return more than one row and you will get an error. You should use `IN` instead.

```
SELECT 
    ISBN, CopyNo, DateOut 
FROM 
    LOAN 
WHERE 
    ISBN IN (SELECT ISBN FROM Book WHERE Title LIKE '%Stuart Little%');
```

Now your second query. I think the `BOOK` table hasn't got the field `NAME` (Whose name?) . I think the `BOOK` table has got something like `AUTHOR_NAME`?

Then it should looks like

```
SELECT 
    ISBN, Title, YearPublish 
FROM 
    Book 
WHERE 
    AUTHOR_NAME LIKE '%Pan Books%';
```